# Binding multidimensional JSON array in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a json response like below code, and need to know how can i handle this with my current setup, 
currently i can handle only one pair value-key response(id=type),

please refer the code i cant output these to a long list selector

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp5.Resources;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace PhoneApp5
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            var definition1 = new { Name = "" };

            var definition2 = new { id = "" }; //is that true? i want to pull inside the Table1


            string json1 = @"{'Name':'James'}";

            string json2 = @"{
  'Table1': [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'item': 'item 0'
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'item': 'item 1'
    }
  ]
}";


            var example1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json1, definition1);

            var example2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json2, definition2);


            MessageBox.Show(example2.id);
           // ??? i need to do with a long list selector


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about your problem? i cant seem to understand what you're trying to do from your question

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov reference from the previous question that i want to improve is = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047531/deserialization-c-sharp-object-and-passing-values-in-windows-phone-8 , i want to pull this JSON response( http://pastebin.com/9skAKNLK ) to a longlistselector

Comment: Your friend class dosent seem to be matching your JSON. Your json is like: "["id",22,18]"

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov just give me a idea about how can i pull this json, forget friend array but logic is almost same. if its matched whats next?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov http://www.yazilimdilleri.net/YazilimMakale-2815-Windows-Phone-8-LongListSelector-DataBind-Ornegi.aspx look at this i can print out values when i write VALUES in the class but i need these values to pull from JSON response

Comment: deserializing dataset - http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ParseJsonArray.htm

Comment: Please post everything needed to help you, we shouldn't have to reference another question to figure out what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you edited your answer, you can do something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

Then, do this:

```
var myClassList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(e.Result);
longListSelector.ItemsSource = myClassList;
```

That way you're binding your class list to the LongListSelector Control.

Comment: i have updated a code in the question please refer, i need to see these code on a long list selector like id->value, id->value

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120106/how-to-get-json-links-data-binded-to-longlistselector-in-windows-phone  i want to do like that but where is actually i have to deserialize

Comment: please look, this is my current setup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084328/deserializing-a-json-array-to-longlistselector-windows-phone-8