# Deserializing a JSON array to LongListSelector Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile

How can i deserialize this jsonx variable and put it on a longlistselector on windows phone?

Currently i can only echo one string with messagebox. i need key-value sets on a longlistselector.

***edit: this is my answer http://pastebin.com/CcADHaab***

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp5.Resources;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PhoneApp5
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();



            string json = @"{
  'Email': 'james@example.com',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z'
}";

            string jsonx = @"{
  'Table1': [
    {
      'id': 0,
      'item': 'item 0'
    },
    {
      'id': 1,
      'item': 'item 1'
    }
  ]
}";



            Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

           // Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
            // james@example.com
            MessageBox.Show(account.Email);

            list.ItemsSource = new BookList();

        }



        }
    public class BookList : List<Account>
    {
        public BookList()
        {


        }


    }
        public class Account
        {
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public bool Active { get; set; }
            public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
           // public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }

        }

    ///////////////////////////







}
```

and my XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp5.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>



        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <phone:LongListSelector Name="list">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" ( " />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}" FontStyle="Italic" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" )" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
        </Grid>


    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a class to represent your json:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

Set a ObservableCollection property in your Form:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> MyClassCollection { get; set; }
```

and then set the MyClassCollection property to your Deserialized json

```
MyClassCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<MyClass>>(e.Result);
```

That way you're binding your class list to the LongListSelector Control in your XAML:

```
        <phone:LongListSelector Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding MyClassCollection}">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" ( " />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}" FontStyle="Italic" />
                        <TextBlock Text=" )" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

That should work.

Comment: it doesnt... i dont understand, should we use list.ItemsSource? what is ObservableCollection

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingCollections.htm will help